# Mutiple HTTPS Port in Spring Boot (SSL / non-SSL)

Tags: spring-boot, security, https, websecurity

I am not sure what i am doing wrong in my application. Additionally to a HTTPS configured via Spring Boot Properties (application.properties) i want to open a second HTTPS Port.

Code Implementation:

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityCollection;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class HttpConfig {
    
    @Value("${server.https.port}")
    private int httpsPort;

    @Bean // (it only works for springboot 2.x)
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer(){
         TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
             @Override
             protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                 SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                 securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                 SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                 collection.addPattern("/*");
                 securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                 context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
             }
         };
         tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createStanderConnecter());
         return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector createStanderConnecter(){
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
            connector.setScheme("https");
            connector.setSecure(false);
            connector.setPort(httpsPort);
            protocol.setSSLEnabled(false);
            return connector;
    }
}
```

When i now trying to access the application within browser via this additional port (e.g 443) like

```
https://localhost:443/xyz
```

i am getting following error message:

```
Invalid character found in method name ... HTTP method names must be tokens
```

As I understood correctly, this is because the browser now encrypts the request, but it can't be decrypted. Is this correct? Is there a possible way how i can decrypted the request? I know i can change it to HTTP, but this i would like to avoid.

Comment: Hello, have you solved this problem? I am having the same thing. I am trying to open a second port in HTTP protocol but the same error is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Just setting scheme to `https` is not enough. You need to enable SSL with
`protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);` and configure `Keystore`, and set `Keystore` properties
Simply, without SSL, you can not use https

> Documentation of Tomcat says:
> *SSLEnabled*: Use this attribute to enable SSL traffic on a connector. To turn on SSL handshake/encryption/decryption on a connector set this value to true. The default value is false. When turning this value true you will want to set the scheme and the secure attributes as well to pass the correct request.getScheme() and request.isSecure() values to the servlets See SSL Support for more information.